# Image is not store in database mysql workbench iin python django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to save product image in database from my "Product form". But the image is not storing, when i insert the values from the admin part, that time the value can store.

**Models.py**

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
photo = forms.ImageField()
```

**views.py**

```
def add_product(request):
    success = False

    if request.method == "POST":  

   product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)


   if product_form.is_valid():            
       success = True

       photo = product_form.cleaned_data['photo'] 
       category = Category.objects.get(name=product_form.cleaned_data['category'])
       title = product_form.cleaned_data['title']  
       type= product_form.cleaned_data['type']
       description = product_form.cleaned_data['description']

       product = product_form.cleaned_data['product']
       quantity = product_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
       price = product_form.cleaned_data['price']

       new_product = Product(category = category, title = title, photo = photo, product = product, quantity = quantity, price = price,type=type,description=description )
       new_product.save()
       new_product_form = ProductForm()
       ctx2 = {'success':success, 'product_form':new_product_form}
       return render_to_response('advertisement/ad.html', ctx2 , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   else:
   product_form = ProductForm()
   ctx = {'product_form':product_form}
   return render_to_response('advertisement/ad.html', ctx , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**settings.py**

```
IMAGES_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/img/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static'),
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view handling from `ProductForm` will receive the file data in `request.FILES`, which is a dictionary containing a key for each `FileField`( image , file whatever ) in the `form`.

So the data from the above form would be accessible as `request.FILES['photo']`.

Comment: if your form is valid then why don't you put pprint in photo ?

Comment: cant understand..where i have to put print?

Comment: below the `photo = product_form.cleaned_data['photo']` pprint.pprint(photo)`

Comment: i added this line, it show error "global name 'pprint' is not defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66378/discussion-between-rajasimon-and-geetha).